# Why do I need to activate firebase everytime I open vs code?

Tags: flutter, firebase

Everytime I open vs code, I need to activate firebase from the beginning, i.e. firebase login to flutterfire configure including exporting the path as export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin".

Why does it not configure itself everytime instead of 'flutterfire: command not found'?